# Fetching A String in Another String Using Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm iterating through a global array containing lines like:

```
/abc/def/ghi/jkl_123/mno1281/ieu
```

I have to fetch the expression `"jkl_*"`. Please provide some way to get it done.

I'm trying to get it using:

```
str=/abc/def/ghi/jkl_123/mno1281/ieu
values=str.match(/jkl_(.*)\//)[1]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> in `block in process_ddfs_log': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)

Comment: What exact output are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Removed `[1]` and added `?` base on your regex

```
(\/jkl_(.*?)\/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gW5pJ6/2)

Output:

> MATCH 1
>   1.    [13-20] `jkl_123`
>   2.    [17-20] `123`

Notes:
`.*` - as many times as possible
`.*?` - as few times as possible

Comment: `.*?` can be replaced with `[^\/]*` (not sure OP needs that part of the string though).